# Type mismatch error when calling another sub

Tags: vba

The following code gives me a type mismatch error. I've tested HideTabs by having an internal array of variants and it worked. Could someone help?

```
Public Sub MainSub()
    Dim tab_names As Variant
    tab_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Call HideTabs(tab_names)
End Sub

Public Sub HideTabs(ws_names() As Variant)
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

Comment: @MátéJuhász This is not the problem, however. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591458/7778672). You can iterate over an array just fine. In fact, `For Each` works on every object that correctly implements a `NewEnum() As IUnknown` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can write as follows. You do not need the () as passing variant ByVal to a sub.

```
Public Sub MainSub()
    Dim tab_names As Variant
    tab_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    HideTabs tab_names
End Sub

Public Sub HideTabs(ByVal ws_names As Variant)
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Now it's giving me a run-time error: Subscript out of range. (I'm positive that "Sheet2" and "Sheet3" exist.)

Comment: Do you have a sheet2 and a sheet3 in ThisWorkbook? Check for any white space in the sheet names or hidden characters.

Comment: I've tried different names as well..It still says Subscript out of range.

Comment: What happens when you type ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Select and  hisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Select  ? i.e. just simply executing those statements to see if can be selected? I assume you are running this from a standard module in ThisWorkbook? i.e. the one with the code in.

Comment: @inarion : I have no doubt you have more experience than I with this. However, it works for me as is. I guess I can suggest OP does that but does it work for me but not for them?

Comment: @Inarion I did test it. And it ran fine.

Comment: @Inarion  have made an edit just to show I am not going more crazy than I already am by putting a gif in.

Comment: No worries. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In `MainSub` you define `tab_names As Variant` while the parameter to `HideTabs` is expected as `ws_names() as Variant`.

One is a `Variant`, which can store (amongst every other simple type and objects) an array, while the other is a `Variant Array` which can store `Variants` (each of which can store an array in turn).

So in effect you're trying to pass a scalar as parameter where an array is expected.

To fix your code, make sure both declarations are using the same type (`Variant Array`, as an implicit array in a "scalar" `Variant` seems to be not usable with `For Each`).

```
Public Sub MainSub()
    Dim tab_names() As Variant
    tab_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    HideTabs tab_names ' "Call" is obsolete. Don't use it.
End Sub

Public Sub HideTabs(ByVal ws_names() As Variant)
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

---

As presented by [QHarr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591345) the parentheses are not required - it would work without them. However, you eliminate the need to check the `Variant` argument for a contained array if you directly require an array.